# Laptop won't boot after BIOS settings change

Tags: linux, boot, laptop, bios, cmos

The laptop is an Asus X55C from 2013 running a dual boot Win/Mint on a SATA SSD.
Lately I noticed multiple Ubuntu entries in the BIOS boot menu (even when my SSD was removed from the laptop) and yesterday, after seeing 6 of them, I tried to remove a couple directly from the BIOS. After saving the laptop couldn't boot anymore.
The screen doesn't even turn on, the Numpad led turns on for a second, the power button stays on and the fan starts spinning after a while.

I tried every method I know for resetting the CMOS but none worked: booting without battery, pressing the power button for 1 minute without laptop and CMOS battery, shorting the CMOS battery compartment. I even removed the Mobo from the laptop and left it completely unpowered overnight.

I also tried re-installing the CPU and sticking in additional ram (the ram is soldered on so I couldn't take it out).

I suspect something went horribly wrong after the settings change but apparently it's not the CMOS.

EDIT1: To be more clear, the laptop doesn't even POST, it is impossible to open the BIOS menu. When the board is powered on, nothing happens.

EDIT2: After some time I am sure that the UEFI chip on the board has corrupted. I tried to flash the chip and restore the BIOS with an EEPROM programmer. Unfortunately I wasn't successful and couldn't get any data either because the chip is dead or the motherboard interferes with the programmers clamp.

Comment: Are you able to start in BIOS (not clear - I do not mean boot the computer). If so, reset BIOS to Default, save and then see if the computer starts.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. The screen doesn't even turn on (I also tried an external monitor).

Comment: Maybe see if you can get the machine serviced at a local shop

Comment: You need to force-install the BIOS, which requires professional help.

Comment: Simply removing items from the boot folder might prevent the machine from *booting*, but *not* from getting to BIOS. Perhaps the SSD has some issue preventing booting. Try removing the SSD and going to BIOS and/or booting with a USB flash drive, e.g., one with WinPE or Ubuntu Live, plugged in. If that does not work, it's definitely time for pro repairs.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried booting from a live USB but I cannot reach the BIOS.

Comment: The suggestion was to remove the SSD, then try to access UEFI ("BIOS") settings and it's really the logical troubleshooting step in this situation. I must reiterate @DrMoishePippik 's comment, that's exactly how it is. Either you did something else you aren't disclosing, there's a hardware failure or both.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author has indicated that "After some time I am sure that the UEFI chip on the board has corrupted." so the question cannot be answered without the further diagnostic capability